# How do I count the number of days between 2 column dates that only have a value of 1 in the calendar table - postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, days

I have a calendar table which displays all the dates with a column that indicates if the date is a business day (1,0).

Is there a way to count the number of business days between 2 dates in a table?

MILESTONE_TABLE

| KEY | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2018-12-31 | 2019-01-07 |
| 002 | 2018-01-03 | 2019-01-07 |
| 003 | 2018-01-02 | 2019-01-06 |

CALENDAR_TABLE

| DATE | BUSINESS_DAY |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-12-31 | 1 |
| 2019-01-01 | 0 |
| 2019-01-02 | 1 |
| 2019-01-03 | 1 |
| 2019-01-04 | 1 |
| 2019-01-05 | 1 |
| 2019-01-06 | 0 |
| 2019-01-07 | 1 |

In this case, I'd like for the Business Days between the 2 milestone dates to be:

DESIRED_RESULT

| KEY | START_DATE | END_DATE | DAYS_BETWEEN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2018-12-31 | 2019-01-07 | 5 |
| 002 | 2018-01-03 | 2019-01-07 | 3 |
| 003 | 2018-01-02 | 2019-01-06 | 3 |

Comment: `BETWEEN` in SQL is inclusive so your `DAYS_BETWEEN` will 1 greater then the counts you show. Is that what you want or do you want the count you show?

Comment: @Jessica, please see the updated answer after the edit

Answer (score 0):

The following is standard SQL but should work in PostgreSQL.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(BUSINESS_DAY) AS DAYS_BETWEEN
FROM CALENDAR_TABLE
WHERE DATE >= '2018-12-31'
AND DATE <= '2019-01-07'
AND BUSINESS_DAY = 1;
```

If you would like to have the other elements in the resulting table (maybe for a join?) then you can just add them in the `select` clause.

After your edit, I am assuming that the data in the milestone_table is wrong and the start date is meant to be 2019. The following query should work which makes use of nested queries. It has been tested using sqlite.

```sql
SELECT KEY, START_DATE, END_DATE, (
    SELECT COUNT(BUSINESS_DAY) 
    FROM CALENDAR_TABLE 
    WHERE BUSINESS_DAY = 1 
          AND START_DATE <= DATE  
          AND DATE <= END_DATE
) AS DAYS_BETWEEN FROM MILESTONE_TABLE;
```

I recommend against using `DATE` as the name of your columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

First off your sample data would not generate the desired results given the problem description. For example key 002 dates 2018-01-03 to 2019-01-07 includes every date in the calendar table(subject to inclusion of ending date) so that is 6 business days not 3. Even adjusting the year 2018 to 219 changes the result but still does not produce the desired result. Now for the needed query.  
Since your indicator is either 0 or 1 and assuming 1 indicates a business you just sum the business_day column where the calendar date is within specified date range. (See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b913f6cf17f934220f9038f87213cac1))

```
select m.key, m.start_date, m.end_date, sum(c.business_day) days_between 
  from  milestone m
  join  calendar  c
    on (c.cal_date between m.start_date and m.end_date) 
 group by m.key, m.start_date, m.end_date 
 order by m.start_date;
```